# Pygame closing right after opening

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a little game using Pygame, but it closes right after I start it. Here is the code of a game cycle:

```
while True:
  clock.tick(FPS)
  rookie.rect_prev_pos = rookie.rect.x, rookie.rect.y
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
  screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
  screen.blit(rookie.image, rookie.rect)
  all_sprites.draw(screen)
  all_obstacles.draw(screen)
  update()
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    detector.rect.move_ip(-move_speed, 0)
    rookie.rect.x = detector.rect.x  
  if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    detector.rect.move_ip(0, -move_speed)
    rookie.rect.y = detector.rect.y
  if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    detector.rect.move_ip(move_speed, 0)
    rookie.rect.x = detector.rect.x
  if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    detector.rect.move_ip(0, move_speed)
    rookie.rect.y = detector.rect.y
  if keys[pygame.K_LCTRL]:
    move_speed = 10
  else:
    move_speed = 5
  collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(rookie, all_obstacles, False)
  if collisions:
    for detector in detect_sprites:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(detector, collisions[0]):
            if rookie.rect.centerx < detector.rect.centerx:
                rookie.rect.right = detector.rect.left
            else:
                rookie.rect.left = detector.rect.right
            if rookie.rect.centery < detector.rect.centery:
                rookie.rect.bottom = detector.rect.top
            else:
                rookie.rect.top = detector.rect.bottom
            offset_x = (rookie.rect.centerx - detector.rect.centerx) / 2
            offset_y = (rookie.rect.centery - detector.rect.centery) / 2
            new_pos_x = rookie.rect.x + offset_x
            new_pos_y = rookie.rect.y + offset_y
            new_pos = (new_pos_x, new_pos_y)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), (rookie.rect.centerx, rookie.rect.centery), (new_pos_x, new_pos_y), 5)
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(100)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (rookie.rect.centerx, rookie.rect.centery), new_pos, 5)
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(100)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 255), (rookie.rect.centerx, rookie.rect.centery), new_pos, 5)
            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(100)
            rookie.pos.lerp_ip(new_pos)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Tried changing the final string and checking the syntax. Expected the game to work for longer than one second. The game just opens and closes after a moment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and the error traceback from when you launch your python script from a console.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your game loop is exiting too quickly, causing the game to close. Try adding `pygame.time.delay()` at the end of the loop to slow it down a bit.

Also make sure `pygame.init()` is called before any Pygame functions are used.

Are you setting `pygame.display.set_mode()`? This needs to be properly created before entering the game loop.

Comment: I'm wondering about the quality of this answer.  Of COURSE the game loop is exiting too quickly.  That's the symptom.  The question is, why would that happen?